# Find indices where array changes

Tags: matlab

I have an array something like this:

```
[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 ... ]
```

I want to find the indices where 0 changes to 1 and 1 changes to 0. So for the following array:

```
changes = [5 10 14 17 20]
```

I know how to use find and a vector predicate expression like `find(A > 3)` to search for simpler conditions, but this has me stuck. I could write a big loop and do it, but I feel there must be something built-in or otherwise easier to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

A very simple approach which works with all values as start would be:

```
changes = find(diff(value))+1;
```

This will also return the expected result `changes = [5 10 14 17 20]`.

Answer (score 3):

Figured out a solution.

```
find(circshift(value, [0, 1]) ~= value)
```

For my application, the array is guaranteed to begin and end with 0s, otherwise it will not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Dennis K's solution works for your binary data.  If you wish to find transitions in general,  I recommend Run Length Encoding.  I don't think MATLAB has a builtin, but (shameless plug), you can use [seqle](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?search_submit=fileexchange&query=seqle&term=seqle) .